# How to add duplicate letters in an empty list with a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

Im trying to build a simple "HangMan" game to improve my poor python class skills

but I have run into a problem..

When a word has 2 of the same letters (for example "Test") it will only add the first letter
and never the second in my for loop, is there a way to check if there are duplicates using a for loop?

edit: tried to add the code but it didn't work so Im posting a pictrue of it
Here is the code:

```
print("HANGMAN!!!!")

val = input("Enter a word ")
lst = []
lst2 = []
class Hangman:
    def __init__(self, val, lst, lst2):

        self.val = val
        self.lst = lst
        self.lst2 = lst2
        print("The word has", len(self.val), 'letters')
        z = len(self.val)
        for n in range(z):
            self.lst2.append('_')
        print(self.lst2)

        #print(list(val))
        self.lst = list(val)
        #print(self.lst)

    def guess_time(self):

        res = input("Please enter a letter: ")

        y = 0
        for x in self.lst:
            if x == res:
                print(self.lst.index(x))
                new_lst = self.lst.index(x)
                print("Correct letter")
                self.lst2.pop(new_lst)
                self.lst2.insert(self.lst.index(x), res)
                print('inserting the letter at', self.lst.index(x))
                #Here is the problem if the word has 2 of the same letters

            y += 1
        print(self.lst2)

h = Hangman(val,lst, lst2)
i = 6
while i > 1:
    h.guess_time()
    i -= 1
    print("You have ", i, 'tries left')
    if i == 1:
        print("GoodBye")
```

Comment: post code here for other people to help better and test the app, (select all the code ctrl+a, press tab and again ctrl+a, and paste it here then

Comment: What exactly didn't work when you tried to paste the code as text into the question? It'd be much easier for us to help you if you added it as text.

Comment: And please be more careful with your spelling. :)

Comment: what's your expected output ?

Comment: sorry, Got it to work now some problem with the copy paste
I want it to find all the duplicate of a letter in the input for example "test" has 2 "t" but it will only add the first never the second

Comment: Instead of invoking `self.lst.index(x)` in you `for x in self.lst:` loop, try to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) as in `for i, x in enumerate(self.lst):` then `i` is the index of `x`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to pass `lst` and `lst2` to the `__init__` function: you could (and probably should) initialize `self.lst` and `self.lst2` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
for i, x in enumerate(self.lst):
    if x.upper() == res.upper():
        print('Correct letter')
        self.lst2[i] = x.upper()
    else:
        print('Incorrect letter')
```

---

Also:

- `lst` and `lst2` don't need to passed into the `__init__` method.
- You never need `self.val`.
- It's not good practice to take input and print stuff inside functions like this.
- `y` does nothing.
- Technically you don't need lists either but, you can use them.

So you can change the program like this:

```
class Hangman:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.lst = list(v.upper() for v in val)
        self.lst2 = ['_'] * len(val)

    def guess_time(self, letter):
        success = False
        for i, x in enumerate(self.lst):
            if x == letter.upper():
                self.lst2[i] = x
                success = True
        return success

    def solved(self):
        return self.lst == self.lst2

def main():
    word = input('Enter a word: ')
    guesses = 6
    hangman = Hangman(word)
    print(f'The word has {len(word)} letters')
    print(''.join(hangman.lst2))
    for guess in range(guesses):
        letter = input('Please enter a letter: ')
        s = hangman.guess_time(letter)
        if s:
            print('Correct')
        else:
            print('Incorrect')
        print(f'You have {guesses - guess - 1} guesses remaining')
        print(''.join(hangman.lst2))
        if hangman.solved():
            print('Well done!')
            break
    print('Goodbye')
```

Comment: yeah I know there are some issues with the code but it's not the final version yet, just got caught in the for loop issue, so now I can continue wit it thank you

Answer (score 0):

use `enumerate` function to get the index and value at same time from a list. And instead of removing/deleting the  letter better to replace it with the different letter or character or number ( which won't come in the word /list) and when the value/letter is matched then for that index add the value in the `self.lst2[index]=res`

here is code

```
def guess_time(self):

    res = input("Please enter a letter: ")

    y = 0
    for index, value in enumerate(self.lst):
        if res==value:
            print(index)
            self.lst[index] = '~'
            print('correct letter')
            self.lst2[index]=res
            break

    y += 1
    print(self.lst2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could keep each letter lowercase and the index in a dict:

```
print("HANGMAN!!!!")

val = input("Enter a word ")
lst = []
class Hangman:
    def __init__(self, val):

        self.val = val
        self.letter_index = {} # also you can use a defaultdict if you are familiar with
        for i, l in enumerate(self.val):
            if l in self.letter_index:
                self.letter_index[l.lower()].append(i)
            else:
                self.letter_index[l.lower()] = [i]

        print("The word has", len(self.val), 'letters')
        self.lst = ['_'] * len(self.val)

        print(self.lst)


    def guess_time(self):

        res = input("Please enter a letter: ").lower()

        y = 0
        if res in self.letter_index:      
            for i in self.letter_index[res]:  # you may want to pop the key
                print("Correct letter")
                print('inserting the letter at', i)
                self.lst[i] = self.val[i]

        print(self.lst)

        if '_' not in self.lst:
            print('Congratulations you won!')
            return True

        return False

h = Hangman(val)
i = 6
done = False
while not done and i > 1:
    done = h.guess_time()
    i -= 1

    if not done:
        print("You have ", i, 'tries left')
        if i == 1:
            print("GoodBye")
```

**output:**

```
HANGMAN!!!!
Enter a word Test
The word has 4 letters
['_', '_', '_', '_']
Please enter a letter: t
Correct letter
inserting the letter at 0
Correct letter
inserting the letter at 3
['T', '_', '_', 't']
You have  5 tries left
Please enter a letter: e
Correct letter
inserting the letter at 1
['T', 'e', '_', 't']
You have  4 tries left
Please enter a letter: s
Correct letter
inserting the letter at 2
['T', 'e', 's', 't']
Congratulations you won!
```